# 301 redirect coz of change in URL structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website which is currently build on Wordpress. It is a News website and hence there are closely around 3000 posts.

Our SEO team is suggesting to change the URL structure from
`Post name` to `Custom Structure`.

`news.com/financial-budget-2018/` change to `news.com/politics/financial-budget-2018/`

Need to know if:-

1. If will have to define *301 redirect rule* for each of the 3000 posts in the `.htaccess` file.
2. Whether this should be handled in PHP, where I can do a check of the url segments and accordingly search in the database for the matching new url and then redirect them.

Or any other better way of handling this

Comment: [This might be handy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257912/redirecting-all-posts-after-changing-url-structure-with-htaccess). It sounds similar to your issue.

Comment: Next time, don't just bold a bunch of random words/sentences. It makes the text messy and harder to read.

Comment: Try and change it on a test server. WP might actually be able to handle that automatically if the prefix, like `politics`, is the posts category.

Comment: You will need to create redirects for each old url.  see: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/change-wordpress-site-permalink-structure/

Comment: I believe @MagnusEriksson is correct. WordPress will handle this for you.